# How to Connect MongoDB with Java Program

Tags: java, mongodb, driver, connectivity

I want to connect My Java Program with Mongo DB database. Below I have written my Java Program.But It's giving some Error.

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.WriteResult;
import org.bson.*;

public class JavaMongo{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {   
           MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");

        for (String name : database.listCollectionNames()) {

            System.out.println(name);
        }

        mongoClient.close();

        }   
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
           System.out.println(e);
        }   

    }   
}
```

> I have following error

[Errors on my terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKEk2.png)

Comment: You imported everything but `MongoDatabase`. Also, never post images of errors. Copy from your terminal and paste it as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You had Miss the  Creating Credentials  statement . So Basically this Error Showing try this code.

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.WriteResult;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;  
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase; 
import org.bson.*;

public class JavaMongo{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {   
           MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
           // Creating Credentials 
          MongoCredential credential; 
          credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb", 
             "password".toCharArray()); 
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");

        for (String name : database.listCollectionNames()) {

            System.out.println(name);
        }

        mongoClient.close();

        }   
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
           System.out.println(e);
        }   

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import "com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase" for using MongoDatabase Interface.

Answer (score 0):

## maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

===========================================================================

## application.properties

```
server.port = 8080
spring.data.mongodb.database=user_db
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

===========================================================================

**for reference use below link:(step by step explanation)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Tq2Q7EzhSA&t=7s